# How does my container injects a bean which is not marked as @stateful/@stateless, etc?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am having some problems understanding Java CDI.
I have a stateful bean which receives per injection a some objects:

```
@Stateful
public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    private MyDAO myDAO;
}
```

and this is the DAO:

```
public class MyDAO{
}
```

I thought it would not work, because I have not defined the bean as @Stateless, @Stateful, etc.

But it works.

The question is: what scope will this bean have? Will it be a stateful bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context MyDAO has a Dependent pseudo-scope which means that it will follow the lifecycle of the bean into which it is injected (in your case EJB stateful MyBean bean). Everything explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_the_dependent_pseudo_scope).